# SQL Picking Top Date out of the Date Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table with a date column. I want to be able to group these dates by Item field of some type. For example I might have a column called Item and within the Item field there may be 500 entries. Item 12345 might have 5 entires, each with a price. I want to be able to pull out all of the Items, grouped by the newest date.

```
031126-2M1                          8/10/2011 12:00:00 AM   7.8678
031126-2M1                          7/22/2011 12:00:00 AM   9.5620
031126-2M1                          7/15/2011 12:00:00 AM   8.8090
```

In this example, I want to show the item with the closest date, 7/15/2011 so I can use that Price of 8.8090. The list would then show the other items, some may have one entry, others might have many, but I want to show all of them with the closets date. Need Help!

Thanks

Comment: @gabrielVa: Quit being a jerk & tag your questions with the database.  You've been asked numerous times, and have the acceptance rating to show you participate.  This is the last time I'll provide the courtesy to those who want to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MS SQL Server version...

```
WITH
  sorted_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY item_date DESC) AS row_id,
    *
  FROM
    item_data
  WHERE
    item_date <= getDate()
)

SELECT * FROM sorted_data WHERE row_id = 1
```

Answer (score -3):

selct * from table 
where This = that
Group  by something having This.
order by date desc.

having "THIS"  should be in the query itself.

hope this helps..

Cheers

Comment: That appears to be one of the most non-answers I've yet seen on SO.  Please could you expand it slightly?

Comment: I answered this question before any style rejustment, on that moment it was for me the most elegant answer.. btw I can't help this comments shows everything on one line.